# How can I convert peptide sequence into binary code

Tags: python, binary

```
bin_dict = {
'A':'10000000000000000000',
'C':'01000000000000000000',
'D':'00100000000000000000',
'E':'00010000000000000000',
'F':'00001000000000000000',
'G':'00000100000000000000',
'H':'00000010000000000000',
'I':'00000001000000000000',
'K':'00000000100000000000',
'L':'00000000010000000000',
'M':'00000000001000000000',
'N':'00000000000100000000',
'P':'00000000000010000000',
'Q':'00000000000001000000',
'R':'00000000000000100000',
'S':'00000000000000010000',
'T':'00000000000000001000',
'V':'00000000000000000100',
'W':'00000000000000000010',
'Y':'00000000000000000001'
}

seq1="ACDE"

bin_string=''
svm_string=''
for letter in seq:
    code = bin_dict[letter]
    print code
```

out put of this code is coming out like this

```
10000000000000000000
01000000000000000000
00100000000000000000
00010000000000000000
```

My first question has been solved I got the output in desired manner, AS @goncalopp suggested I am trying to reintroduce my Qtn for better understanding.

```
 Fig 1.
```

Step first:                          Seq = ACDE

Step two: through this binary code position of int "1" would be calculated as given below

```
       10000000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000
       |                    |                    |                    |
      1:1                   1:22                1:42                 1:58
```

Step three: calculated positions

```
            1:1 1:22 1:42 1:58
```

Step four:

```
       Ultimate output should be a text file having code only 1:1 1:22 1:42 1:58  to represent the string ACDE
```

now please suggest me what would be the python code for this.

Comment: Also, please write just one question per post.

Comment: For your first question, you just need to add a comma to your print: `print code,`. I don't fully understand your second questions. Do you just want to find the position of the 1s? You may want to rephrase the question, since most people on SO won't know what a peptide sequence is.

Comment: @ goncalopp i have edited my post please suggest the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print("".join([bin_dict[l] for l in seq1]))
```

This will combine the individual strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
binstring = ''.join([bindict.get(l) for l in seq1])
```

should do the first.  For the second I would have another dictionary and use that.

Since you ultimately need only the 1 positions and each item grows the sequence by 20 you could probably skip straight to that:

```
pos_dict = {'A':1, 'C':2, 'D':3, 'E':4, 'F':5, 'G':6, 'H':7, 'I':8,
             'K':9, 'L':10, 'M':11, 'N':12, 'P':13, 'Q':14, 'R':15,
             'S':16, 'T':17, 'V':18, 'W':19, 'Y':20 }
S = 1
for Seq in Seqences:
    so_far = 0
    for l in Seq:
       print "%d:%d" % (S, so_far + pos_dict.get(l,-999)),
       so_far += 20
```